# How can I print to the console with Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Is it possible to print the volume of the last X candles in Pine Script v5 in the console?

I've tried something like

```
//@version=5
indicator("Volume Last 20 Bars", overlay=true)

// Array para almacenar el volumen de las últimas 20 barras
var float[] volumeLast20Bars = array.new_float(0)

// Función para imprimir la información de volumen en la consola
f_printVolumeInfo() =>
    for i = 0 to array.size(volumeLast20Bars) - 1
        log.info("Bar ", i, " - Volume: ", array.get(volumeLast20Bars, i))

// Agregar el volumen actual al array
array.push(volumeLast20Bars, volume)

// Mantener solo los últimos 20 valores en el array
if array.size(volumeLast20Bars) > 20
    array.shift(volumeLast20Bars)

// Imprimir la información de volumen cuando la barra está cerrada
if barstate.isconfirmed
    f_printVolumeInfo()
```

But it doesn't work.

I need to extract volume information from an active via console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need arrays for that. The following should do:

```
if barstate.islast
    for i = 19 to 0
        log.info("Bar {0} - Volume: {1}", i, volume[i])
```

Remarks: 0 is the latest bar, 19 is the 20th bar from the current.

[image]

---

Edit 1 - Based on the comment below:

So I added the code so that you can get from Bar X to Bar Y, from both the left (Start of the data) and the right (End of the data). Below are screenshots of the same:

From Bar no. 35 from the right

[image]

To Bar no. 4 from the right.
[image]

You can also see the Date-Time information matching in the chart. Changing the format is a relatively simple process, so I will leave that to you. I have also included a line that plots from the first to the last bar, for clarity.

The code:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="TEST", shorttitle="TEST", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

vw = ta.vwap(hlc3)
plot(vw, title="VWAP", color=#ff9800)

// From bar number A to bar number B (FROM THE LEFT - START OF HISTORY)
A = 4
B = 35
if barstate.islast
    line.new(x1=A, y1=close[bar_index-A], x2=B, y2=close[bar_index-B])
    for i = bar_index-A to bar_index-B
        log.info("Bar {0} - Time: {1} VWAP: {2}, Volume: {3}", i, str.format_time(time(timeframe.period, i), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", syminfo.timezone), vw[i], volume[i])

// From bar number C to bar number D (FROM THE RIGHT - END OF HISTORY)
C = 4
D = 35
if barstate.islast
    line.new(x1=bar_index[D], y1=close[D], x2=bar_index[C], y2=close[C])
    for i = D to C
        log.info("Bar {0} - Time: {1} VWAP: {2}, Volume: {3}", i, str.format_time(time(timeframe.period, i), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", syminfo.timezone), vw[i], volume[i])
```

Comment: ok thks !!

I need export the vwap too. My code looks like


//@version=5
indicator(title="TEST", shorttitle="TEST", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

vw = ta.vwap(hlc3)
plot(vw, title="VWAP", color=#ff9800)

if barstate.islast
    for i = 50 to 0
        log.info("VWAP {0}, Bar {1} - Volume: {2}", vw[i], i, volume[i])

If I need the bar time (formatting yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm) and select the range of bars (for example, export from bar XX to bar YY)?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please check the edited answer above.

Comment: Oh thank you !! 

I see that this solution does not work for me, since I want to export the VWAP indicator information for a candlestick history, but the console has limited capacity.

Do you know any way to do it?  

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly you mean here. The log does give VWAP output. Where do you want to export the data to?

Comment: I need export the VWAP historical data from an active on M5 to CSV

Comment: If that is all you need, you can straight-up export chart data, which exports OHLC values along with any other indicator on the chart. You can find the option in the drop-down next to the layout selector.

Comment: ok but it is a payment option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257181/discussion-between-powerbucker-and-rakesh-poluri).